# What are code Relocations ins AArch64, are they the same as the relocation for dynamic linking?

Tags: assembly, linker, arm64, relocation

Reading the manual for GNU ASM I came across the syntax `#:abs_g0_nc:` and `:pg_hi21:`. This code loads different bit ranges of a value into a register, yet it is called relocation. I know what relocation is for dynamic linking, so what is the difference here?

Comment: These suffixes select a different relocation type for the immediate operand.  I.e. they instruct the linker to place different parts of the immediate into the operand during the relocation phase.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic-linking relocations are references across boundaries between program and libraries, or between two shared objects.

The same kind of relocation is needed when making a `.o` that's going to be linked in a later step into an executable or shared object.  The assembler doesn't know the exact (absolute or relative) address of the target symbol, so it creates a relocation entry in the `.o`.

At (static) link time, `ld` will fully resolve as many of those relocations as it can (so they don't have to get done by the dynamic linker every time the program runs).  Any addresses that can't be fully filled in will still have a relocation entry in the final linked executable / library.  (e.g. an absolute address in a jump table in a position-independent executable will have a "text relocation" if it's in `.rodata`)

Comment: You might want to expand the answer to explain how suffixes like `:abx_g0_nc:` interact with relocation and what their effect is.

Comment: @fuz: I don't know those ARM64 details; you might want to post an answer yourself.